# [__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a39930

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, chartboost

I want to implement chartboost in my project & i have a demo of chartboost from
https://github.com/ChartBoost/client-examples

i have added my  cb.appId and  cb.appSignature in appdelegate
but when i run this code it shows error of [__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKeyedSubscript:]
i have checked using breakpoint debugging it shows error after this code in ExampleAppAppdelegate.m

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[ExampleAppViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ExampleAppViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[ExampleAppViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ExampleAppViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

so,in appdelegate what should i have to change to overcome this error?

In my project in appdelegate.m i have added this code in applicationdidbecomeactive method i have added following code to include chartboost

```
-(void) applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    Chartboost *cb = [Chartboost sharedChartboost];

    cb.appId=@"51c3e47d17ba475b0b000002 ";
    cb.appSignature=@"392392796fb9a1603bcd2deb0aa9a17442ccd83d";

    // Begin a user session. Must not be dependent on user actions or any prior network requests.
    [cb startSession];

    // Show an interstitial
    [cb showInterstitial];
    if( [navController_ visibleViewController] == director_ )
        [director_ resume];
}
```

but still it gives same error

Comment: Have you tried changing your compiler to "Apple LLVM compiler 4.2" ?

Comment: hey it is solved. It was ios version problem when i have tried it on ios-6 it shows no error. thanks for the response